# Ubuntu 19.04 Gnome freezes randomly

Tags: drivers, gnome, suspend, freeze, 19.04

I have Ubuntu 19.04 Gnome latest, my Kernel is `Linux Lenovo-V310 5.0.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP`.
Freezing occurs randomly but some features become disabled before the freeze. for example Media keys won't work.
Freeze happens on 2 am, and I restarted the laptop after 19 minutes on 2:19. I left the laptop turned for 15 minutes after freeze, but the log is available until 1:59 as you see in the picture, the highlighted line.

I installed extensions "intel Cpu power manager", "Persian Calendar", "Clip board" and "Network Manager".

My Laptop specification is: Intel core i7 Cpu, Intel 520 GPU + AMD R430 2GB, 8 GB DDR4 RAM, 256 GB SSD.

After force shutdown and restarting, everything works well.
The brief of last syslog before the freeze is here: (highlighted line)

[image]

Comment: it seems a Wireless error occurs depend on log
`wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending`

Comment: You have either a bad GNOME extension, or you've added Nautilus scripts/extensions... one in particular called FolderColorMenu. Remove FolderColorMenu and retest. If you still have a problem, temporarily disable ALL GNOME extensions, restart gnome-shell, and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Thanks I will try. I had freezes from Ubuntu, Pop_OS & even Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your BIOS. Use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, note the version number returned, go to the Lenovo web site, and check for a newer version.

Second, check the firmware in your SSD. Use `sudo lshw -C disk`, note the manufacturer and the firmware version, and check at either the Lenovo web site, or SSD manufacturer's web site for an update.

Third, run a memory test. Go to **http://www.memtest.org** or **https://www.memtest86.com/** (use the second link to get the latest free version), and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the tests to confirm good memory.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the tests, I already tested my RAM & my SSD and it was good. but I didn't tested the firmware.

Comment: @H.Najafi status please...

Comment: I tried different kernels, same result, just updated my bios and it fixed the problem.
hopefully. since update, didn't notice any freezing.
also didn't got any errors during memory test.